# How to update just a portion of window in SDL?

Tags: raspberry-pi, sdl

I write a program based on SDL2, for Raspberry pi 3 and use a 3.5" Waveshare SPI LCD. It is slow because of SPI to parallel interface.

In my program I draw lines, text & do other graphical staffs, then I call  *SDL_RenderPresent* to update screen. This function is quite slow.

In my application just a little portion of the window is modified, each time. I find a solution to update the only small part of the window in **DirectFB** instead of the entire display, and the result is awesome. How can I update just a specific rectangle in SDL?

Answer (score 0):

`SDL_RenderPresent` might be "slow" because it does vertical synchronization.

From wiki.libsdl.org:

> If you're stuck on the whole renderer idea coming from 1.2 surfaces and blitting, think of the renderer as your main surface, and SDL_RenderCopy() as the blit function to that main surface, with SDL_RenderPresent() as the old SDL_Flip() function.

And from wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide:

> SDL_Surface/2D rendering: surfaces still exist, but it is recommended that instead of using SDL_Surfaces, you use SDL_Textures with an 2D accelerated renderer (SDL_CreateRenderer()) where possible.

So if you render to a texture instead, then you can use `SDL_RenderCopy` (which take a clipping rectangle) to copy parts of the texture to your main `SDL_Renderer`.

When you are finished rendering, use `SDL_RenderPresent` to show/present it on the display. This might – depending on the backend – just wait for vsync and then do a buffer swap.

Disclaimer: I have never used the `DirectFB` backend with SDL2; only the `OpenGL` one.

Comment: isn't any solution to update just a portion of screen in SDL?

Comment: @SAP Yes, by rendering to a `SDL_Textures` and then using `SDL_RenderCopy` to choose which portion to update (by using the `dstrect` argument).

Comment: There is `SDL_RenderDrawLine` where works on the first argument _renderer_. How to draw line directly on the texture?

Comment: Can i use `SDL_RenderSetClipRect` ?